How can an ad for "$6,000 off MSRP" not mean $6,000 off MSRP?
I was drawn to a new car dealership because of this ad:
"Big end-of-year sale, $6,000 off MSRP on 2024 (models)"1

1 Must finance with us.
 (small text)

So I asked to see the car in the car and it said on the window "MSRP: $30,000". I asked if I could expect to pay $30,000-$6000 = $24,000 an they said, no, if I financed with them, and my credit score was really exceptional, then they might get the price near the number on the window. Note that $30,000 was the price of the car three months ago, before there was the sale.
Was I mistaken for thinking the price should be $24,000 based on their ad? Or I am just misunderstanding the language somewhere?

Often times these ads include a disclaimer that there are only X specific cars available for this promotion (sometimes even including the VINs of said cars).

We can't possibly answer this based on your summary of the wording of the ad and the fine print. We'd need to see the actual details - and if they're a reputable dealership then it's 99.9999% certain the fine print will have said something that made it entirely legit.

I've given the full text of the fine print that is one that ad. There was a little "1" and then that message about financing is tiny text at the bottom.

Is the word "off" missing from your quote of the ad?

Most car dealers are crooks, liars and cheaters. They will screw you over for every penny: How do you know when a are dealer is lying? Their lips are moving!


then they might get the price near the number on the window.

It depends on what other things they are allowed to tack onto the price. You do realize that many states have a sales tax, which they would add to the price you pay.
They may want to charge you for transportation, safety inspection, dealer prep. This is even before they want you to pay for undercoating, scotch-guard  and a special extended warranty.
They will always try to be very careful that the fine print will be perfect and the state laws followed.
They could say you have to be a new graduate, or a veteran or active duty military, or that it is only in the ugly color, or the one with every possible option.
It could also apply to only a few cars.
I know the following wasn't the entire fine print:

Fine print: Must finance with us.

But that is a very important one, they will only make that offer of $x below MSRP because they know they will make some profit on the loan.

if I financed with them, and my credit score was really exceptional,
then they might get the price near the number on the window

They can limit access to the deal by only making this offer if you have a very high credit score. That could eliminate many people. They may also be charging a non-competitive interest rate, or expecting a large down-payment.
We haven't even discussed the number of years or the value of your trade in.

Car prices, these days, are insanity.  Its like the COVID run up and shortage of parts is still going on.  The issue is, of course, that most of your friends and neighbors are willing to pay what the car dealers are demanding.  So prices will stay high.
Car dealers lie.  The small text allows them to do this without getting successfully sued for false advertising.  Often times they will say the promotional price only applies to a single VIN.  That VIN, will have already have been sold.
Additionally, to qualify for the advertised price, you have to qualify for certain rebates.  Examples might include a recent college graduate, a veteran, or even a repeat customer.  Only a small percentage of people will be able to qualify for the promotional price even if the VIN was on the lot.
The goal is to get you to come in, forget what motivated you to be there, fall in love with the car, arrange your finance through them and negotiate poorly.   The reason they can get away with this is many gladly fall for the trap.
